# Inner padding of a Text with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In the UI design of a screen, I have a very big text (`180 sp`). To follow the design though I need to have just a `16 dp` padding around the text, including the inner vertical padding of the text. The problem is that even if I put a padding of `0 dp` the inner padding is already bigger than `16 dp`

Is there a way to set to 0 the inner vertical padding of a Text with Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score -1):

Actually that is innate, it follows material guidelines. If you wish to disable it, an alternative would be to look at the source of Text. You could just copy the source and make modifications to meet your requirements. It is doable, and is a recommended practice to customize behavior for your needs.

Comment: Mmm that would be unmanageable. And it would mean that the component is not following the open/close principle. You should not need to modify the code of a component to customize the behaviour unless the component, for any reason, must force you not to override the behaviour. Can you point me to this recommendation, please?

Comment: It was said in one of the videos from Nick Butcher. Don't remember the exact one now. It was also in a codelab. Perhaps the layout or the theming codelab, Which are again both by Nick as far as I know. It is usually done to modify styling because Compose uses CompositionProviders under the hood.